# rm: cannot remove *: Is a Directory

Tags: rm

I installed "darling" and now want to delete it, but this shows up:

```
rm: cannot remove 'darling': Is a directory
```

When I ran `rmdir` it says:

```
rmdir: failed to remove 'darling/': Directory not empty
```

Even ran `sudo umount darling`, still no luck.

Comment: Please give more information. Which Ubuntu version are you running? What is "darling" and how did you install it? What was the exact command you tried to remove it with? Where did you get that command from?

Comment: @sotirov: Your edit makes it appear as if the error messages were quoted literally, but they obviously aren't.

Comment: @Tilman you are correct. Fixed

Comment: I’ve put an answer below re how to remove directories - but it looks like perhaps you’re actually trying to uninstall darling. That’s a very different matter - and how you do that depends on how you installed in the first place. If that’s what you’re trying to do, please edit your question with the details (of your Ubuntu version, how you installed), or post a new question specifically about uninstalling it.

Comment: Which "darling" is your darling? Is it this [Darling](https://www.darlinghq.org/) ... If yes, then please add the output of `dpkg -l darling; dpkg -s darling; dpkg -S darling` and probably tell us a bit on how you installed it.

Answer (score 2):

`rmdir` will only remove empty directories.

`rm` without options will only remove files

`rm -d` behaves like `rmdir`

`rm -r` will remove directories and any contents - be careful, especially if you use wildcards!

Comment: I don't think that answer will help sorting out @user1740826's confusion.

Comment: @Tilman - yes, good point! Hopefully we’ll get some more information in edits after our comments.